# Error: Package "@ionic/angular-toolkit" has no builders defined

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, command-line-interface

```
[error] Error: Package "@ionic/angular-toolkit" has no builders defined.}
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\krishikhoj\krishikhoj-ionic-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:121:19)
    at RunCommand.runSingleTarget (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\krishikhoj\krishikhoj-ionic-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:245:53)
    at async RunCommand.runArchitectTarget (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\krishikhoj\krishikhoj-ionic-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:295:24)
    at async RunCommand.validateAndRun (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\krishikhoj\krishikhoj-ionic-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command.js:136:22)
    at async runCommand (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\krishikhoj\krishikhoj-ionic-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:224:24)
    at async default_1 (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\krishikhoj\krishikhoj-ionic-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js:70:31)
```

Comment: Did you install ionic ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try to install - **npm install @ionic/cordova-builders**

Then goto **angular.json** inside "ionic-cordova-build" and "ionic-cordova-serve" and **replace**

"builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-build"

with

**"builder": "@ionic/cordova-builders:cordova-build"**,

- for more info visit- https://ionicframework.com/blog/updates-to-ionic-angular-toolkit/

Answer (score 5):

Below Solution work for me:

> Step: 1

- npm install @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest @ionic/cordova-builders

> Step: 2

- Replace below code in angular.json
- ```
       "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-build",
  ```

- ```
       "builder": "@ionic/cordova-builders:cordova-serve",
  ```

[image]

> Step: 3 - *Not mandatory*

- Remove node_module and reinstall

> Output
> [image]

Answer (score 2):

I kicked out the issue by using this solution.

1. run
   `sudo npm install -g @ionic/cli@latest` 
   to install latest ionic package and run 
   `npm outdated`
   to get outdated packages.
2. run
   `npm install package_name@latest --force` (replace 'package_name' with the outdated package name) for every package shown in outdated package list
3. Ignore any warning during update.
   **TIP:*Updating all the outdated packages saves you from app's low performance and improves security***

Answer (score 2):

For future references: [here an explanation](https://ionicframework.com/blog/updates-to-ionic-angular-toolkit/) and how to fix it. I also needed to edit the angular.json to change the cordova builder.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install - npm install @ionic/cordova-builders

Then goto angular.json and replace

```
@ionic/angular-toolkit
```

with

```
@ionic/cordova-builders

The angular.json will be like this:

        "ionic-cordova-serve": {
          "builder": "@ionic/cordova-builders:cordova-serve",
          "options": {
            "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build:production",
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-build": {
          "builder": "@ionic/cordova-builders:cordova-build",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            }
          }
        }
```